# how to use powershell to input file to executable?

Tags: powershell

How to let PowerShell use file as input to an executable?

for example, a directory like this

```
test.txt
text.exe
```

how to use test.txt as the input of test.exe in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$settings =get-content "Path\test.txt"
$filename = "Path\text.exe"
Start-Process -FilePath $filename  -ArgumentList $settings
```